# Why does this python for loop increments my list?

Tags: python, for-loop

why does this for loop increments the integers on my list? I really don't understand, I'm new to python.

Thank you.

```
testlist = [1,4,2,4,3,4,4,4,4,5]

for x in testlist:
    print(testlist[x])
```

Output:
4
3
2
3
4
3
3
3
3
4
4

Expected:
1
4
2
4
3
4
4
4
4
5

Comment: I think you meant `print(x)` instead of `print(testlist[x])`.

Comment: Try `print(x, testlist[x])` and see what `x` actually is. It iterates over all _values of elements_ of `testlist`, not their indices.

Comment: I suggest you try to change your `print` to `print(x)` and also to `print(testlist[0])`, `print(testlist[1])`, `print(testlist[2])`... It might give you a hint

Comment: `for x in testlist` iterates the list's elements, not its indeces.

Comment: oh I got it! Thank you everyone who answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll want to change that to

```
testlist = [1,4,2,4,3,4,4,4,4,5]

for x in testlist:
   print(x)
```

this is because x is being made equal to `testlist[loopcounter]` so its thinking when loopcounter = 1 it should read the value at `testlist[1]` which is 4 and then print the value of `testlist[4]`

apologies for any formatting issues

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
for x in testlist:
    print(x)
```

When you are looping through a list, it does not return the index (unless you make it do that). Looping through a list returns that item in that list. When you do `testlist[x]`, it takes the value of x and finds the item at that index. If x is one and you find `testlist[x]`, it returns 4 because the second item is 4. This is shown in your list, `[1, 4, ...]`. (The index of iterables starts at zero in Python, so 1 is the second item.) Let me know if you need more of an explanation of loops or indexing.